# Perturbations of an integrable system with no resonant tori

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, perturbation-theory, resonance, complex-systems, integrable-systems

Suppose I have a Hamiltonian $H_0$ which is just a collection of $N$ non-interacting harmonic oscillators.  Written in action-angle coordinates $(J_i, \theta_i)$ we have $H_0 = \sum_{i=1}^N \omega_i J_i.$ Now further suppose the frequencies $\omega_i$ are *non-resonant*, i.e. for any non-zero set of integers $n_i$ we have $\sum_i n_i \omega_i\neq 0.$

Is the perturbed Hamiltonian $H(J,\theta; \lambda) = H_0(J)+\lambda V(J,\theta)$ also integrable for small enough $\lambda$?

That seems to me like a strong claim, but if we write $V$ in terms of Fourier modes $$V(J,\theta)=\sum_{n\in Z^N} V_n(J) e^{in\cdot \theta},$$
then we can find a conserved quantity $J_i'$ which is a perturbation of the original conserved quantity
$$J'_i=J_i+\lambda \sum_{n\in Z^N}\frac{n_i}{n\cdot \omega}V_n(J)e^{in\cdot \theta} +\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2).$$
The correction was chosen to ensure that $\{J_i',H\}=0$ to first order in $\lambda$. This is possible because $n\cdot \omega\neq 0$ for any set of integers $n$. It seems to me that this argument could be continued to solve for $J_i'$ to any order in perturbation theory.

Is it true non-perturbatively that any small enough perturbation of a non-resonant set of harmonic oscillators is integrable? Does this have any connection to the [Kolmogorov-Arnold-Moser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem) (KAM) theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application of the usual KAM theorem requires some conditions on the invariant tori of the unperturbed Hamiltonian. The first one is nondegeneracy:
$$
\left|\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial J}\right| \neq  0
$$
so that the frequencies are functionally independent. In your case, it is precisely the opposite:
$$
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial J} = 0
$$
A second condition is isoenergetic nondegeneracy:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial J} & \omega \\
\omega & 0
\end{vmatrix}\neq 0
$$
and in your case for $n>1$ (which is always assumed for KAM):
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & \omega \\
\omega & 0
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$
Thus KAM does not apply in your case.

For your perturbative approach, what you are essentially describing is Birkhoff's theorem. The issue with small divisors problem is not necessarily that a term of the perturbative series diverges. It rather that due to the density of the rationals and irrationals. Even if $\omega$ is irrational, the denominators can get arbitrarily small and the convergence of the series is therefore hard to justify. In fact the divergence of the perturbation series is more the rule than the exception. From Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* (Appendix 7):

> However, we can show that this exact reduction is generally not
> possible, and formal series for canonical transformations reducing a
> system to normal form generally diverge.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry I did not accept sooner. I found the arXiv references 1311.7334 and 1401.5748 which treat the degenerate case in my question and discuss the accumulation of KAM tori near fixed points. In short it seems it is indeed not integrable.